# Matcher functions should return an object in the following format when using jest assertion

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocha.js, webdriver-io, matcher

im getting the error below when im running test against multiple browser using wdio and mocha as testing framework, same assertion is working fine if its running against only one browser

```
describe ('Landing Page test suite',()=> {
    before(()=>{
        browser.url('/')
    })

    it ('1. Page should be loaded proeprly',()=>{
        p.header.waitForDisplayed()
            expect(p.header).toBeVisible()
    })
})



Unexpected return from a matcher function.
Matcher functions should return an object in the following format:
  {message?: string | function, pass: boolean}
'[{"message": [Function message], "pass": false}, {"message": [Function message], "pass": false}]' was returned
```

here is code sample
https://github.com/Amrkamel1/wdExample.git

run: npm i
npm run test

Comment: I see. The problem is very specific to WDIO that uses Jest matchers for assertions, not Jest itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"toBeVisible" is a Jest matcher and can't be used with WebdriverIO. Please use the correct matcher: https://webdriver.io/docs/api/expect.html#tobedisplayed

Comment: great thx i will try that, but how then its working fine when i use one browser in wdio config instead of multiremote config